# Comando init e after_theme_support WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender a funcionalidade desses comandos no WordPress:

```
init
```

e

```
after_theme_support
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você quis dizer `add_theme_support` ou `after_setup_theme` ao invés de `after_theme_support`. Bom, lá vai:

O `add_theme_support` é uma função chamada geralmente no `functions.php` para adicionar componentes do tema.

`add_theme_support('COMPONENTE_DO_TEMA', array('PARÂMETROS_DO_COMPONENTE','...','...'));`

O `after_setup_theme` é um parâmetro usado na função `add_action` para que uma função execute assim que o tema termine de ser carregado, logo após a execução de `functions.php`. Geralmente usado para realizar configurações e mudar opções do tema.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','SUA_FUNÇÃO_AQUI');
```

O `init` é um parâmetro também usado na função `add_action`, mas, diferente do `after_setup_theme`, ele executa uma função assim que o WordPress inicializa, mas antes dos `headers` serem enviados. Geralmente utilizado para inicialização de plugins.

```
add_action('init','SUA_FUNÇÃO_AQUI');
```

A grande diferença entre o `after_setup_theme` e o `init` é que na execução do `init` o usuário já estará devidamente autenticado.

Você pode procurar por mais detalhes na [documentação do WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) e exemplos de uso do [init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/) e do [after_setup_theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/) no guia de referência de código do WordPress.